Little creatures on islands controlled by brothers
I’m looking for a book where king has sons and he wants to test them. So he give them little creatures (I think hamsters) to control (I think by flute).
I think there were 3 brothers. One brother attacks the second brother's island and enslaves his hamsters to attack the third brother.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a hardcover, paperback, or e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?
